# SQL Select Top 20 Records with Subquery & Pivot Rows to Columns

Tags: mysql

**Input:** I have a table that has a list of accounts and what they spent each day. For simplicity, we will say that the table has the following fields: account, account_id, date, sales.

**Output:** The end goal is to get a report of the Top 25 accounts and list their sales for the prior 8 weeks. The report will have the account, account_id, and then 8 additional columns for each of the prior 8 weeks with the sales summed in each column.

**Problem 1:** I'm having trouble grabbing the Top 25 accounts. I wrote a subquery to sum the prior month's sales for each account and grab the Top 25 by using the where clause with an in operator, but subqueries don't support in operators.

**Problem 2:** I am unsure how to pivot the 8 prior weeks into columns.

```
select
        yearweek(date,1) as year_week
        ,date_add(makedate(year(date),1), interval week(date,1) week) as first_day_of_week
        ,account_id
        ,account
        ,sum(sales) as total_sales
from daily_sales
where date >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 8 week)
and account_id in (  select
                                    account_id
                                from daily_sales
                                where year(date)=2018 and month(date)=11
                                group by 1
                                limit 25)
group by 1,2,3,4;
```

Comment: can you show your sample data?

Comment: I cannot due to security reasons. The fields are account_in (INT), account (VARCHAR), date (DATETIME), and sales (FLOAT). The date field is populated with every date of 2018 for every account.